# PostgreSQL functions select*

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

How can I use:

```
select * from <some_table>;
```

in a `FUNCTION` in Postgres?

Comment: You mean returning from a function? Otherwise the question doesn't make any sense. You then should specify what you tried and what error you got.

Comment: You might want to provide more information what you want to achieve, what did you tried, how did fail, and how you'd want it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  my_function() RETURNS INTEGER AS '
   DECLARE
      your_record your_table%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN

      FOR your_record IN SELECT * FROM your_table  
      LOOP

      --
      -- You can access fields of your table using .
      --    your_record.your_field
        ...
      END LOOP;


   END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
STABLE;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  my_function() RETURNS INTEGER AS '
   DECLARE
      your_record your_table%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN

      SELECT * INTO your_record FROM your_table;

      --
      -- You can access fields of your table using .
      --    your_record.your_field

   END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
STABLE;
```

---

EDIT:

With join returning a record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  my_function() RETURNS SETOF record AS '
   DECLARE
      your_record record;
   BEGIN
      --
      -- You should specify a list of fields instead of *
      --
      FOR your_record IN SELECT * FROM your_table INNER JOIN ...           
         RETURN NEXT your_record;
      END LOOP;
   END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
STABLE;
```

To use my_function(), you have to specify fields and datatypes:
[See details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742180/postgres-functions)

Comment: But in case I want to make a join with other table?

Comment: @cmax: same thing. just join it. assuming you know how to write SQL join - you can do the same thing in function. Perhaps you need to ask more detailed question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a smipler method, if you want to use SQL in the function, use SQL language in the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getallzipcodes() 
RETURNS SETOF zip AS
$BODY$
     SELECT * FROM zip;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

And this might be useful too (how to call the function)

```
SELECT function_returning_setof(); -- Wrong!  
SELECT * FROM function_returning_setof(); -- OK!  
SELECT function_returning_scalar(); -- OK
```

[reference](http://wischner.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/creating-stored-procedure-function.html)