# Postgres functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make a select query with joins. This should be written in a function. My approach didn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2()
RETURNS SETOF record AS'
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
    for r in SELECT * FROM messages_wall INNER JOIN location ON
         messages_wall.id = location.id
         loop
    return next r;
    end loop;
end; '
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

I should call this function from a .net application. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM test2() AS tabletest2 (id integer, name text);` if you really wanna use a function, but a view is better in this case

Answer (score 2):

Instead joining table into your function, you may use view.

RETURNS  SETOF **your_view**;

You probably have to define r with the appropriate datatype too:

```
r your_view%ROWTYPE;
```

or

You have to specify the fields and datatype.

```
SELECT * FROM test2() AS fields_1 as INTEGER, fields_2 AS ... ;
```

Comment: Ok, how can I do this using Npgsql, in ado.net?

Comment: You can't use SETOF messages_wall because that table is joined with the location table, resulting in a table with more columns than messages_wall. You'll need to define a new type that has the appropriate fields in it.

Comment: It works indeed with r messages_wall%ROWTYPE. But what if I want to return the values from different tables:
for r in SELECT messages_wall.id, location.name FROM messages_wall INNER JOIN location ON messages_wall.id = location.id

Comment: @Barry, I didn't remark the JOIN... Only specifying fields and datatypes works.

Comment: Ok, as I understand, if I specify fields and datatypes, I cannot use ExecuteReader() with command type stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

For your example wrapping a join in a (PL/pgSQL) function is unnecessary. As Luc M has mentioned a view would be simplest and fastest.

If you insist on having a function though your next choice should be an [SQL function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) - more info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-TABLE-FUNCTIONS) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#AEN40353).